# SSH forwarding not working in macOS Monterey

Tags: terminal, network, ssh

I am trying to get port forwarding working on my Mac with macOS Monterey. I have a script that works on multiple other machines, including older Mac and Windows machines using Ubuntu Linux subsystems. The script contains a single line of interest and exists just to make sure the call is exactly the same on all machines. It is:

```
ssh -t $SERVER -L $PORT:127.0.0.1:$PORT
```

I can successfully ssh into this machine. I can even successfully run the port forwarding script, which appears to connect at first. But when I try to connect to it in the browser (I'm using this to forward a JupyterLab server), then it reports the error (in the terminal):

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

As indicated, three times immediately, and then it reports that repeatedly as I presume the browser continues to retry. One copy of the full error report using `ssh -vvv` is available at the end of this post.

I have also tried using the following call to use IPv6:

```
ssh -t $SERVER -L $PORT:[::1]:$PORT
```

But I get the same exact error output.

I have also checked that the Firewall is off in System Preferences > Security & Privacy.

In another thread, someone also suggested running `telnet 127.0.0.1 $PORT`, which outputs:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Full error report in `ssh -vvv` mode:

```
debug1: Connection to port 7774 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 7774 requested.
debug2: fd 12 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 12 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 12 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: receive packet: type 92
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 3: zombie
debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 7774 for 127.0.0.1 port 7774, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 58513 to 127.0.0.1 port 7774, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 9/10/11 sock -1 cc -1)
```

Comment: This doesn’t appear to be an SSH issue, but an issue with whatever service you’re trying to port forward to.  That’s the one rejecting the connection.  What port is it?

Comment: It's port 7774. I wondered about this, but it works on 2 windows WSL systems and 1 old MacBook. I just connected on a different computer, for example. I've wondered if it's perhaps some privacy settings or something on the local machine? But I don't know what to look at besides the firewall.

Comment: You’re connecting to the exact same server by those Windows machines and old Mac?

Comment: Yes, exact same server, exact same jupyterlab instance

Comment: Got it.  Out of curiosity, do you have to authenticate to whatever it is you’re connecting to?

Comment: I do have to authenticate, yes. But that works for normal ssh access from this machine, and appears to work with port forwarding as well until attempting access jupterlab from the browser.

Comment: Does the non working script set any environment variables?

Comment: Just $PORT, which is used as in the above script. $SERVER is not set, I just put it here as an example

Comment: If possible, momentarily disable the firewall. What happens? Run `sudo lsof -i :$port` to find out what executable, if any, is listening on that $port.

Comment: I just ran `sudo lsof -I :7774` and it gave no output.